# SQLite Getting empty result from any query

Tags: sqlite

Here is weird question: do i make SELECT query that will always return nothing from some database?Preferably fast,but not necessary.

For example,i have some random table Events,and i can do that simple way,by looking for record that will probably never exist:

```
"SELECT * FROM Events WHERE EventName = 'ajsiLfjh28v0djkf9409fda'
```

But that is very ugly solution.Is there a better way to do it?I can't find anything,mostly because i am unsure what to look for.

Comment: Why are you trying to return nothing? Why query at all?

Comment: I have few classes where getting any kind of query results is crucial and don't want to change them,and i also can't just send them empty data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build on this basic empty query:

```
select 0 where 0;
```

You can make any query return nothing by throwing AND 0 at the end of the where clause (unless there is no where clause.)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand but if you want to make sure no result s are returned add a limit of 0

```
SELECT * FROM Events LIMIT 0
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM Events WHERE null!=null
```